# Magento2 how to get shipping method price in payment page?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, payment

[image]Magento2 how to get shipping method price in payment page
In shipping methods details is coming from .html file.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to display shipping method price
Under Shipping Method in payment page
Matso Standard - (Delivery)----shipping price

Comment: Magento by default shows shipping price in checkout sidebar. Where you want to display shipping price?

Comment: In payment page we get shipping method details there i need to display shipping price..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first look, many guys think it will be easy. But, from my view, it's not easy.

[image]

A) Shipping total:

Component: `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js`
Template: `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html`

B) Shipping information:

Component: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information.js`
Template: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information.html`

As we can see, shipping total should go with tax component.

Now we need to add shipping price to shipping info section. What I should do first?

1) Using a different Js component for shipping information. We need to use XML.

**Create a new custom module** `Vendor/Module`, create `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping-information</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2) Creating Js component:`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping-information.js`

The most important note is that our Js will extend from `Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping`. We need to merge `Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping` and `Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information` together.

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/sidebar'
], function ($, Component, quote, stepNavigator, sidebarModel) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping-information'
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isVisible: function () {
            return !quote.isVirtual() && stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
        },

        /**
         * @return {String}
         */
        getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
            var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

            return shippingMethod ? shippingMethod['carrier_title'] + ' - ' + shippingMethod['method_title'] : '';
        },

        /**
         * Back step.
         */
        back: function () {
            sidebarModel.hide();
            stepNavigator.navigateTo('shipping');
        },

        /**
         * Back to shipping method.
         */
        backToShippingMethod: function () {
            sidebarModel.hide();
            stepNavigator.navigateTo('shipping', 'opc-shipping_method');
        }
    });
});
```

3) Creating html template: `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping-information.html`

We should copy first content from `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information.html`

```
<!-- ko if: (isVisible()) -->
<div class="shipping-information shipping-new">
    <div class="ship-to">
        <div class="shipping-information-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship To:'"></span>
            <button class="action action-edit" data-bind="click: back">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'edit'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="shipping-information-content">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('ship-to') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ship-via">
        <div class="shipping-information-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Method:'"></span>
            <button class="action action-edit" data-bind="click: backToShippingMethod">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'edit'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="shipping-information-content">
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>

            <!--=== Here is our change ===-->

            <!--==== End our change ===-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

The second logic we will copy from `module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js`, but need to edit

```
    <!-- ko if: isBothPricesDisplayed() -->
        <div class="totals shipping excl shipping-tax-test">
            <div class="amount">
                <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="price"
                      data-bind="text: getExcludingValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="not-calculated"
                      data-bind="text: getExcludingValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totals shipping incl">
            <div class="amount">
                <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="price"
                      data-bind="text: getIncludingValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="not-calculated"
                      data-bind="text: getIncludingValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: isIncludingDisplayed() -->
        <div class="totals shipping incl">
            <div class="amount">
                <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="price"
                      data-bind="text: getIncludingValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="not-calculated"
                      data-bind="text: getIncludingValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: isExcludingDisplayed() -->
        <div class="totals shipping excl">
            <div class="amount">
                <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="price"
                      data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
                <span class="not-calculated"
                      data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

Clear your browser cache and see the result

[image]

Comment: Hi in step 3 <!--=== Here is our change ===--> what changes should i here Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: Hi Khoa TruongDinh I am not shipping price..can you please help me out

Comment: hi How about your current issue? It's not clear to me? Could you update your question with what you're trying?

Comment: shipping price should be displayed after shipping method in checkout page as your output image is correct as i need in same way Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: ` <!--=== Here is our change ===-->` needs to add the second logic to this part. Did you try?

Comment: Yeah I am not getting shipping price..Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: Did you clear or disable your cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83723/discussion-between-trilok-kumar-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: Its working correctly thank alot Khoa TruongDinh..

Comment: Can we a get as free when an order is played by Free Shipping

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i need to get the shipping rate alone in custom.js, where the js is defined in checkout_index_index.xml